# How can I delete the content of an entity in coreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entities

I use core data in my objective c proyect, but when I open the app I want delete the last content into a entity. I use this code that should be work:

```
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
   [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

   NSError *error;
   NSArray *items = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
   fetchRequest = nil;


   for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in items) {
       [_managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
   }
   if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
   }
```

But I get this error where entityName is the name of my entity:

> [error] error: exception handling request:  , "entityName" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject. with
>   userInfo of (null) CoreData: error: exception handling request:
>    , "entityName" is not a subclass
>   of NSManagedObject. with userInfo of (null)

How can I delete the content correctly and without errors? What is the correct way?

Comment: Check that your managed object context has been initialised (ie, it isn't null)

Comment: Please read the error message: *"entityName" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject* is pretty clear. It must be the name of the entity not the literal string `"entityName"`

Comment: My  managed object context has been initialised @Paulw11

Comment: And I send the correct name -> @"entityName" like NSString, without quotes with the entity name @vadian

Comment: The error message says you don't.

Comment: @user3745888 You're entity is literally called "entityName" in the model?  That's.... very odd.

Comment: Did you try NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"entityName" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];